# Which type of regression should I use?

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm an engineering student and I'm facing a problem related to regression. 
My data set consists of m measurements $(\alpha_i, y_i)$ with normal distributed errors in $y$ as well as in $\alpha$.
The angle measurements are in $[-\pi/4, \pi/4]$.

The functional connection between $\alpha$ and $y$ is known as
$sin(\alpha_i)*x_1 + cos(\alpha_i)*x_2 = y_i$ for $i=1,...,m$.

The equation is linear in $x_1$ and $x_2$.

My question now is which type of regression method should I use to obtain good estimates for $x_1$ and $x_2$. 
I never made a regression without an intercept term before. Are there any other preprocessing step necessary?

Comment: I made some simulations with ordinary least squares algorithms and figured out that if most of my angle data are around 0 the variances of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are quite similar and for data around $\pi/4$ the variance of $x_2$ is much higher. Can this be avoided by some rescaling or similar approaches??

Comment: Are you sure this problem is identifiable?

Answer (score 0):

If there was no random error for the angle measurements then a linear regression model would be the way to go.  For example, in R:

```
> n <- 50
> alpha <- runif(n, -pi/4, pi/4)
> tau <- matrix(c(sin(alpha), cos(alpha)), nrow=n, ncol=2,
+     dimnames=list(NULL, c("sin(alpha)", "cos(alpha)")))
> x <- c(1, 2)
> y <- (tau %*% x) + rnorm(n)
> angle_dat <- data.frame(tau, y)
> lm(y ~ 0 + sin(alpha) + cos(alpha), angle_dat)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + sin(alpha) + cos(alpha), data = angle_dat)

Coefficients:
sin(alpha)  cos(alpha)  
    0.8036      1.9271
```

However, since you have random error in the observed values of the $\alpha_i$ things are far more complicated.  This type of model is known as a *measurement error model*.  A good introduction / survey of these types of models can be found at [Measurement Error in Epidemiological Studies](http://www.biostat.washington.edu/~yanez/b578D/materials/gail03.pdf).  I'd imagine that you can find some direction there or by following the many references at the end of the document.